# Can I grow mint from cuttings indefinitely?

Tags: hydroponic, cuttings

I would like to grow mint hydroponically from cuttings. I wonder if I can grow mint from cuttings indefinitely?

- what is the plant lifespan?
- can I grow cuttings from plant generation after generation indefinitely?

Comment: never tried mint from cuttings - it sends out root runners so aggressively it's always easy to a get a rooted section, and you don't have to get through the "no roots, lots of transpiration" phase.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Mint cuttings root quickly in water.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Mint is one of the most responsive plants to use by cutting. Cut just above a set of opposite leaves and 3-4 in. down from that for one cutting. Mint is very invasive, as long as you provide the right conditions it should continually be the same as the previous cutting. Just cut the flowers off and don't let it go to seed, this would go from cloning to sexual reproduction (the next generation).